# how can I call CompletionHandler method?

Tags: swift

I have already created a method but do not know how to pass parameter and manage response parameter.

```
class func postWithURL(serverlink:String, methodname:String, param:NSDictionary, key:String,  CompletionHandler : @escaping  (Bool,NSDictionary) -> ())
```

thanks

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have constant File for web service_alomafire. I have write method for request. but I do not know how to call this method from my login controller.

Comment: If you start type method name xcode autocomplete will suggest you a best way to do it. even you don't need to type that; I suggest you to read docs from apple

Comment: see the answer of Sharad Chauhan but don't use NSDictionary in swift 4. Use Dictionary instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can call your method:

```
self.postWithURL(serverlink: "link", methodname: "name", param:NSDictionary(), key: "key") { (bool, dictionary) in
            // you code goes here
        }
```

Comment: can u write code for how to parse response?  suppose I want value from reponse than how can I get. please write sample code.

Comment: The response depends upon how you are getting the data from the server. Also what are you using at your networking layer in your app? I would recommend you to look into Alamofire. Its a very handy swift library to make network requests and handle responses. You can find plenty of examples and help for it.

Answer (score 1):

Example of completion method :

```
func sampleCompletionMethod(name: String, completion:@escaping(Bool)->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

This how you call it :

```
sampleCompletionMethod(name: "Abc") { (result) in
    print("Result of completion : \(result)")
}
```

You method should be without class keyword like this :

```
func postWithURL(serverlink:String, methodname:String, param:NSDictionary, key:String, CompletionHandler : @escaping (Bool,NSDictionary) -> ()) {

}
```

If your function is in some another class, then make an object of that class, for example if class name is `NetworkHelper` then add `NetworkHelper()` to call it.

Call it like this :

```
postWithURL(serverlink: "link", methodname: "POST", param: NSDictionary(), key: "key") { (boolResutl, dictionay) in

}
```

**Edit**: Suggested by Prashant Tukadiya

using `NSDictionary` is bad practice in swift 4. You should use Swift's Native class of `Dictionary`

Comment: using `NSDictionary` is bad practice in swift 4. You should use Swift's  Native class of `Dictionary`